# How to change the orientation of a Landscape Table in pdf file

Tags: tables, pdftex

I have a standard Latex Table that I transpose into Landscape with \begin{landscape} \end{landscape} (lscape package) because the table is very wide. How to rotate this table in the Pdf document such that the landscape table has the same orientation as all the other portrait tables, making the pdf file easy to read? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: use `pdflscape` package rather than `lscape` (same document syntax)

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

Use `pdflscape` package rather than `lscape` (same document syntax)